# Compare JSP database datetime with current time

Tags: java, database, jsp, datetime

So I'm displaying some information from my database on my JSP.

My current code:

```
<c:forEach items="${values}" var="values">
            <tr>
                <td>${values.addTime}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Now what I need is to check if addTime value in my table (which is DATETIME) is past or not. And then change some CSS on  tag depending if it is past or not.

My thought was that I need to get that ${values.addTime} as a Java variable and then I could make new Date object and compare them and after that I could do some if statements and so on But I couldn't even do that so I'm pretty much out of ideas now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably meant `car.addTime` instead of values. The rest of your idea is ok. You can also change your query to give you the values with already set true of false depending on the datetime value compared with current time.

Comment: I changed my code a little. 
But with changing them to true or false depending if it is past or not I still have to display datetime on my page. So I guess I need to do another column into table with boolean value to show it. But still I need to have a if statement to check if this boolean is true or false, so how do I do that?